# Given two arrays A & B with positive integers, find Maximum product of Array A after atmost N operation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

We are given two Arrays of size n with positive integers. we are allowed to modify elements of array A such that `A[i]=A[i]*B[j]` or `A[i]=A[i]+B[j]`, *where 0<=i,j<n*. we are allowed to use each element of array B only once. Find the maximum product of Array A after at most n operation.

The purpose of my question is to look for correct and better algorithms.

example:

```
A={2,3,5};
B={1,6,4};
output= 1080
```

Explanation:

```
A[0]=2+1=3
A[1]=3*4=12
A[2]=5*6=30
product=30*12*3=1080
```

My approach:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int testcases; cin>>testcases;
    for(int i=0;i<testcases;i++){
        int n;cin>>n;
        vector<int>a(n);
        vector<int>b(n);
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cin>>a[j];
        }
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            cin>>b[j];
        }
        sort(a.begin(),a.end());
        sort(b.begin(),b.end());
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            a[j]=max(a[j]+b[j],a[j]*b[j]);
        }
        int answer=a[0];
        for(int j=1;j<n;j++){
            answer=answer*a[j];
        }
        cout<<answer<<endl;
    }
}
```

Howver, it passed only one testcase, and was getting wrong answer for others.

Comment: sorry for small debugging errors, the purpose of question is looking for a better algorithm. i have corrected small debugging errors.

Comment: @def__init__ So are you saying that even after fixing the errors it still only passes one test case? Or have you changed the question?

Comment: yeah, actually there was no error in my actual code when i wrote while give online test for a company, else it would not have even passed sample testcases. just made mistakes in typing at this site sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is wrong.

```cpp
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        a[i]=max(a[i]+b[i],a[i]*b[i]);
    }
```

You're assigning using `i` as index instead of `j`. It should be

```
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        a[j]=max(a[j]+b[j],a[j]*b[j]);
    }
```

Edit: Since you've corrected your input, there's another logical fallacy. Consider the following case:

```
A = [1,2]
B = [1,2]
Your answer = 8
Correct answer = 9 [(1+2) * (1+2)]
```

The algorithm is correct otherwise, but if you don't handle this case, your final answer would be wrong.

Comment: kindly ignore, little i,j mistakes i made in typing at stackoverflow, the purpose of question is not debugging but looking for a better algorithm

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer and taking your time to find the flaws.